# How to set the width of a column which contains an input element?

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code hoping to generate a table whose first column occupies 40% of the total width, while the other columns occupy 10% of the total width. However, what I got are equal width columns.

```
<table >
<col style="width:40%">
<col style="width:10%">
<col style="width:10%">
<col style="width:10%">
<col style="width:10%">
<col style="width:10%">
<col style="width:10%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>head 1</th>
        <th>head 2</th>
        <th>head 3</th>
        <th>head 4</th>
        <th>head 5</th>
        <th>head 6</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="text" val=""></th>
        <th><input type="text" val=""></th>
        <th><input type="text" val=""></th>
        <th><input type="text" val=""></th>
        <th><input type="text" val=""></th>
        <th><input type="text" val=""></th>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Could you not link to collaborative JSFiddle demos in future? It makes it really hard to see what your problem is when other people have heavily altered your original.

Comment: Sorry, I won't next time.

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yr74u957/)

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Yours looks the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/yr74u957/4/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table th {
  width: 10%;
}
table th input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
table th:first-child {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 3</th>
      <th>head 4</th>
      <th>head 5</th>
      <th>head 6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="text" val="">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="text" val="">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="text" val="">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="text" val="">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="text" val="">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="text" val="">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your fiddle works without `table-layout: fixed;` http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yr74u957/3/

Comment: JSFiddle actually gives `table` elements `table-layout: fixed` by default. So the fix part of your answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following rule: `input { width: 100%; }`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/bqzvqfkz/)**

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <col style="width:40%">
    <col style="width:10%">
      <col style="width:10%">
        <col style="width:10%">
          <col style="width:10%">
            <col style="width:10%">
              <col style="width:10%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>head 1</th>
                    <th>head 2</th>
                    <th>head 3</th>
                    <th>head 4</th>
                    <th>head 5</th>
                    <th>head 6</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>
                      <input type="text" val="">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                      <input type="text" val="">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                      <input type="text" val="">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                      <input type="text" val="">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                      <input type="text" val="">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                      <input type="text" val="">
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Even better give them `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving width to td but there is no with specified for table. so you need to add following code to work it properly.

```
table {
table-layout: fixed;
width:100%;
}
```